# How many customers view the blog after their purchase?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Need to obtain # of customer views on blog after purchase (commented on some of the lines to show my thinking), not sure if its the right approach (finding # customers and views) open to any feedback, thanks in advance!

Desired Results: # of customers, # of views made by customers on blogs

*Tables:*

Purchases
[image]

Traffic_events_atl
[image]

How many customers view the blog after their purchase?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.customer_id) as num_cust, -- number of customers
  COUNT(t.visit_id) as page_views -- views made by customers
FROM
  traffic_events_atl t
JOIN
  purchases p
ON
  t.visitor_id = p.visitor_id
WHERE t.property ilike '%blog%'; -- blog specific websites;
```

Including output:
[image]

Comment: so what you are not getting from your query?

Comment: Edited my post to show a output, wasn't sure if its the correct way to get customers and views. Wanted to double check

Comment: don't you think you should use COUNT(DISTINCT p.customer_id) for counting number of customer? you can add some sample data from both tables wit your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want and additional condition on time:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.customer_id) as num_cust, -- number of customers
       COUNT(t.visit_id) as page_views -- views made by customers
FROM traffic_events_atl t JOIN
     purchases p
     ON t.visitor_id = p.visitor_id AND
        t.timestamp > p.timestamp
WHERE t.property ilike '%blog%';
```

Note:  You might want to take multiple purchases for a customer into account.  If so, ask a new question and provide appropriate sample data and desired results.